# Waiting for a script object to load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a jquery script that will be run from the console of google chrome and will analyze a page.
My problem is that when I run the following code:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
alert($('a'));
```

I get a message box with null (bad result)
But if I separate it to to executions like this:

step1:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

step2:

```
alert($('a'));
```

It works great and I get [object] that is my desired result.

The question is what can I do to run this in a single batch?

Comment: Are you putting this code in the ready event?

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "separate executions." I'm sure your code does not have the words "step1" and "step2" in it, but...

Comment: I'm running the code from Google Chrome's console

Comment: Check out this related answer: **[Load ordering of dynamically added script tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38840724/2247494)**

Answer (score 2):

In general, you need to attach a listener on the `script nodes` *onload* event. jQuery will not be available until its fully transfered and executed. Like

```
var jq   = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;

    jq.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
    jq.onload = jq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(!jq.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test( jq.readyState ) ) {
        jq.onload = jq.onreadystatechange = null;
        jq = undefined;
    }
}

head.insertBefore(jq, head.firstChild);
```

The above code is pretty much rocksolid and works in IE6+ aswell.

Comment: Where in it do I add my alert($('a')) ?

Comment: Remember that I'm running it from the Google Chrome Console

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [this](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/109) and check the ready state of the script:

```
jq.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
     alert($('a'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solid way and tested listeners for a complete load of script, try third party libraries like:
http://yepnopejs.com/

Start a script loader from scratch is not recommended, not Today.