# Execution order of dynamically added script tags marked with defer attribute?

Tags: javascript, deferred-execution

I have some applications which dynamically create widgets. Some widgets need some libraries to be included (eg Codemirror, Tinymce, jQuery, ..). These scripts are dynamically added in document when the widget is first created, else they are not included at all (it would be a waste of resources to pre-include all possible widget scripts without them being used in every request).

The widgets can be created either server-side or client-side. In client-side the scripts are added dynamically on page else added as script tags by server in the resulting html output.

If on client, I have noticed that execution order is not respected. For example some Codemirror addons load first (as more light-weight) yet they fail because the main lib s not yet loaded (even though it comes before them as script tag).

I tried using `defer` attribute which according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) **respects the execution order as it appears**, even though scripts are loaded async. Yet I noticed it fails (**note** I use only `defer` attribute not `async`). Tested on Firefox and Chrome so far.

Is this true also for dynamically added script tags?

If not, what can be an alternative in order to respect execution order (**without using onload callbacks**)?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load ordering of dynamically added script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839650/load-ordering-of-dynamically-added-script-tags)

Comment: No I am looking for a solution that is current (2021) and preferably without resorting to callbacks as scripts are out of my control. Something like the defer attribute but for dynamic script tags

Comment: "*without using onload callbacks*" - I don't think it's possible to achieve that.

Comment: @NikosM. The 2021 solution would be to use modules which declare their dependencies in `import` statements, but I suspect your widgets and addons don't support this (i.e. you want to execute them as scripts in the global scope)

Comment: @Bergi these scripts are not necessarily modules. If using callbacks is the only solution (and someone can justify this with some references) then that's the way it is. I can accept such justified answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using callbacks to wait until a script has loaded before attaching a new script on the DOM (which depends on previous script).

However I would expect this procedure to be handled by browser (eg using `defer` attribute).

If someone has a solution in which the browser handles all this interlinking for dynamically added script tags, please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I don't think browsers do this. That's why AMD (asynchronous module definition) with loader libs like require.js was invented - they allow you to load all modules at once and then execute them in the right order. Since then, ES6 modules were introduced as the native solution where browsers handle this.

Comment: What can I say, high hopes :) to eliminate boilerplate code